# Opening PowerPoint after clicking a html link

Tags: javascript, html, powerpoint

I have a link in my webpage. When someone clicks the link I want to start the PowerPoint application in the user's desktop with an image in the slide. There are too many of such links and so I can not create separate ppt files for each links.

I can do the following with excel.

```
<a href="http://localhost/excel/asheet.xls#Sheet2!D4">
 This link will open the Excel file to the second page with the focus on cell D4
</a>
```

So is it possible to do something for PowerPoint like this

```
<a href="http://localhost/template.ppt#image1.jpg">
 This link will open PowerPoint with image1.jpg in the slide.
</a>
```

Or any JavaScript hack will also help.

Comment: You mean you want to open a powerpoint presentation in the browser or having the link start the desktop version of powerpoint?

Comment: I want to start the desktop version of powerpoint.

Comment: Could you consider the option of opening it in the Browser? The reason I ask is for simplicity. It's much harder to get the functionality you're seeking if you choose to open Desktop Version of Powerpoint. It's also probably not safe.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer is correct.  This also assumes they have PowerPoint installed.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer please let me know how you can do it in the browser. It's always better to know something..

Comment: @RaihanAlam Are you using .NET for the server technology?